# CronExpression OR clause in the day of month field?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

Hello I have a simple cronexpression

```
 0 00 00 30 * ?
```

Where 30 gets me the the 30th of each month.  This doesn't return February, so I want something like an OR clause for the day of the month field, but I don't see how to do it yet.  Just to be precise, I want an expression that will give me the 30th or the last day of each month.

Comment: And how is this related to Java?

Comment: @edalorzo this is a Quartz expression, it has6 fields, since Quartz can specify seconds (classical cron cannot)

Answer (score 0):

[The Quartz documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) gives the answer: the "day of month" field should be `L`, for "Last".

(nice addition, I wish vixie-cron had that too)

Comment: I need the specific day, OR the last day, so just using the L won't work for my needs

Comment: Then there's no way to do what you want I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Because the "L" doesn't give you your needs, use multiple triggers that relate to the one job.

E.g.  "0 0 0 30 JAN,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC ?" and "0 0 0 L FEB ?"